# PHPfox feed post category filter

Tags: phpfox

I am using phpfox-3.8.0-premium.

I am looking for functionality like:

Attach category with every feed post and allow user to filter feeds on wall, so please can anyone suggest how to do that? because phpfox doesn't provide categories for feed post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to code that manually, but I do know of a very nice plugin that extends the activity wall and adds that feature.  Check out http://phpfox.younetco.com and the plugin is "Advanced Wall".